# How to improve jackson using in spring configuration

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

My configuration file like that. I want to implement using `jackson` for using json. How I implement below code used for `jackson`.

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/assets/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Comment: You want to use both json and jsp, depending on what the controller produces ("application/json" / "text/html")?

Answer (score 0):

if you need jackson for Rest-Service serialization you need only to put the jackson library in you classpath. spring will find the library there an use it.

in your restcontroller add produces = "application/json"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = "application/json")
public class XXXEndpoint {
}
```